# Deploying Java service fabric application on windows cluster fails - no jFabricRuntime

Tags: java, azure-service-fabric

I'm playing around with service fabric, and have setup a 5-node Windows Server 2016 cluster, where I've successfully deployed C# services from a Win10 machine, and have communicated with said services using both C# on Win10 and Java on Ubuntu.

We'll also need to communicate the other way, so the next step, I thought, would be to deploy [one of the example Java services](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-java-getting-started) onto the cluster. Had to adjust the `ServiceManifest.xml` to run a more Windows-friendly bat file, and i thought that was it. Not so - I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jFabricRuntime in java.library.path`.

I found the `libjFabricRuntime.so` file, but that's rather useless on Windows. Google is not helpful in finding any information on `jFabricRuntime` nor `libjFabricRuntime`.

Is this simply a case of me trying this too early, and I have to wait for the Service Fabric Java SDK for Windows, or is there some other way to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java samples are intended to run on Linux based Service Fabric clusters. I don't think you can get this to work on Windows, because of differences in implementation of the runtimes.

Comment: That's what I feared. Having a Linux cluster is not really an option for us, so it seems SF is not the solution we were hoping for.

Actually, reading the docs[1] it says "Java as a first class built-in programming language is supported for the Linux preview only (Windows support is planned).", so I guess I should just have read that more throughly.

Anyways, thanks.

1): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-create-your-first-linux-application-with-java